# How do you create a C# property that can subscribe to another WinForm control at design time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a property in a control that will act as a viewer that will be able to connect to another non-visual control to show its current status. In this example let’s say that the viewer will simply show the status of *online* or *offline*.

I want to be able to drop a non-visual control, let’s call it a `Heater` of type `IHeater`, on the form and then drop a `HeaterMonitor`. I want to go into the properties of the `HeaterMonitor` and for the custom `Source` property see a list of all of the `IHeaters` currently on the form.

Selecting an instance (`Heater1`) in the `Source` property would subscribe `HeaterMonitor1` to all the status updates generated by `Heater1`.

Is there an existing pattern I can follow as a template?

If it makes a difference I can use .net 3.5 and higher. I selected `data-binding` as a tag, but I'm not sure that is correct because this is  not a database question. But it does seem similar to a `DataGridView` selecting a `DataSource` property.

**Edit #1:**
Based on the comments so far I don't think I emphasized enough what I'm trying to get. I want the property editor to list the eligible `IHeater` controls on the form.  I don't have an issue with creating a regular `IHeater` property that I can assign at run-time.

Comment: are you looking for something like this perhaps ..this is what I gather from your question 
`public IList<Heater> Heaters {get; set;}`

Comment: To have non-UI elements that can be used at design-time in the designer, you can inherit from Component.

Comment: After inheriting from component, it's enough to have public `IHeater Source { get; set; }` property. The propertygrid will show a list of available IHeater instances that you can choose one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have non-UI elements that can be used at design-time in the designer, you can inherit from [`Component`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public interface IHeater
{
    int Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class Heater : Component, IHeater
{
    public int Temperature 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class HeaterMonitor:Component
{
    public IHeater Source { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use them in design-mode (in component tray):

[image]

And select the source this way:

[image]

Comment: I created a project based on the code above (before) you added the additional graphic and low and behold it works!  Seemed way to simple.