# C# Custom Control Properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, custom-controls

I am building some applications that use OPC to control some industrial automation.  I have decided it might be a good idea to create some custom controls for standard things I will use such as buttons and text boxes.  One of my main reasons was that I felt in an ideal pattern the end object i.e. the button is the one who holds information about the OPC item it refers to otherwise in a typical application my Form class gets polluted by tons of variables that are in my mind scoped more global then they should.  I started then by using the Tag property of the button but this requires some overhead code that is the same for each instance.  I felt like the right thing to do is subclass controls that I would like to use and provide properties to configure each one.

With that context in mind my real question is this.  To make it as portable as possible I decided there should a property to define the OPC Group.  I declared a property like this

```
public class OPCButton : Button  
{  
    [Category("OPC")]
    public OPCConnectedGroup
    {
        get { return _OPCGroup; }
        set { _OPCGroup = value; }
    }
}
```

This shows up int the property list when I add the control but I am unable to bind this property even though my Form1 contains

```
public OPCConnectedGroup Connection1 = new OPCConnectedGroup();
```

I have resolved that the way to solve this is to probably create an additional control like OPCGrp that can be added to a Form then the Controls can reference this.  To test I added a property of type Button and sure enough when I added it and browsed to the property it gave me options for all the buttons on the Form.  I have no huge problems with this approach I just want to make sure that Im following a prototypical pattern because I will be responsible for maintaining the control library but not always implementing and Im trying to get it down to a 1-2 step process to implement a control.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: What's the type of `OPCConnectedGroup` is this class made by you?

Comment: Correct.  Its actually going to be a generic interface like 'IOPCConnectedGroup' and provides the custom control access to the OPCGroup to register item/items and remove them

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [How do you create a C# property that can subscribe to another WinForm control at design time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002533/how-do-you-create-a-c-sharp-property-that-can-subscribe-to-another-winform-contr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `OPCConnectedGroup` you can inherit [`Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

This way if you have a property of type `OPCConnectedGroup` in your `OPCButton`, then at design time, you can put instances of `OPCConnectedGroup` on the form, and then if you choose your `OPCButton` at designer, that property of type `OPCConnectedGroup` will show as a drop down list that you can select one of instances that you put on the form for it.

Example:

If I have such `MyButton` and `MyClass`:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyClass MyClassInstance { get; set; } 
}

public class MyClass : Component
{
   public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can put some (or one) instance of `MyClass` on the component tray of the form:

[image]

And then if you select `MyButton` on your form, you can choose one of `MyClass` instances from in property grid:

[image]

Comment: Thanks  Thats basically what I expected but its nice to hear from others.  I also was unaware to inherit Component. I thought I would have to inherit the typical Control

Comment: You are welcome. Components are more suitable for such cases because they are  light-weight and non-visual.

Comment: What would be the best way if I wanted my component to be program scope instead of form scoped ? It occurs to me that the component needs to be created on that form and I would like to avoid something like `OPCConnectedGroup.SetGroup(IOPCGroup)`

Comment: If you want to use a component in designer, so the scope of that component would be `Form`. But your components can have share things that you store somewhere in a static property. the `Somewhere` can be a different class or your same component class.