# What is the code behind linking two components visually?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-controls, treeview

I am writing a custom set of controls for file management consisting of (so far) a TreeView and a ListView component.

What I would like to do, is when I drop the custom TreeView on the form which has a custom ListView, for them to be able to see each other automatically, and provide a dropdown list in the properties window the same way that you would select an ImageList object for the `LargeImageList` property (as depicted below).

[image: Filtered object list]

What is the code I would need in my custom control to have a property that functions the same way, but instead of ImageList, the custom TreeView would show a list of my custom ListView's that are on the form (they may be in containers like the splitter control as well if that makes a difference in the resulting code to solve this), and vice versa.

Comment: [How do you create a C# property that can subscribe to another WinForm control at design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002533/how-do-you-create-a-c-sharp-property-that-can-subscribe-to-another-winform-contr)

Comment: If type of the property is `Control` or `Component`, then the designer automatically list all available components for the property in dropdown.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - testing from that post.  It looks like it should work.  Give me a few minutes and will update on if i had any problems as the person wasn't demo'ing with inherited controls and the linked object was a component, not another control.

Comment: There is no difference between builtin controls and custom controls.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - worked like a charm.  `public ListView Source { get; set; }` love it.  Thank you so much :)   So simple, I was definitely overthinking this that I had to enumerate the form objects and so on, but VS takes care of all that legwork !!     <3

Comment: Great! You're welcome :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei done.  It didn't come up as it is worded differently "subscribe" instead of "link" etc.  Wonder if there is a way to relate the two on SO, as this is a duplicate (same effect), but the terminology used is different.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - just did that.  voted both .. hehe.